# Doing a json decode in php from $_POST

Tags: php, post, json

I'm working with an API that sends JSON data over to a remote server I host. If anyone uses beanstalk I'm basically sending a web hook so you can see the set up of the JSON data [here](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68110-trigger-a-url-on-commit-with-web-hooks)  (its a GIT repository). I can't seem to get the JSON object to decode no matter what I try.

I've tried:

```
$myArray = json_decode($_POST, true);
```

and

```
$decodedText = html_entity_decode($json);
$myArray = json_decode($decodedText, true);
```

and

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myArray = json_decode($json);
```

But every time the decoded JSON comes up `NULL`. The post data is there and so is the raw data but for some reason it's not decoding properly.

Comment: Can you add the output of `var_dump($_POST)` to your answer? Having this it should be easy to answer

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` show you?

Comment: The data will be in `php://input`, but it can only be read once. Are you sure you don't have something else consuming `php://input`?

Comment: This code `json_decode($_POST, true);` tries to decode a whole array so it will always give you an empty result. Try using `json_decode($_POST['var_name'], true);`. To find the var_name use print_r($_POST);

Comment: I've output $_POST and php://input and everything is being passed like it should be but its just the decode that comes up null

Comment: But what are you passing to json_decode? The whole $_POST array or a variable $_POST['var_name']? If you pass the whole array you'll get always a null result.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have hidden characters in your json variable, otherwise it will return null for an invalid json format.

See a similar answer here: [Json decode and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227043/json-decode-and-variable/22228045#22228045)