# JSON decode and variable

Tags: php, json

I have

```
$string = $_REQUEST['COM_node'];
```

it contains the string

```
{"cmp_class":"ProfileReferences","auto_id":"cmp14","forms":[],"parent":{"cmp_class":"PrivateMediaNetworkList","auto_id":"httpdoc"}}
```

When I tried

```
$nodeArray      = json_decode($string, true);
```

returns NULL. But when I given like

```
$string = '{"cmp_class":"ProfileReferences","auto_id":"cmp14","forms":[],"parent":{"cmp_class":"PrivateMediaNetworkList","auto_id":"httpdoc"}}';
$nodeArray      = json_decode($string, true);
```

It works fine. I searched the web, but found no solution.

Comment: I wonder how you are not getting a syntax error for missing parenthesis.

Comment: better to visit the documentation : http://in1.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your $_REQUEST['COM_node'] contains the exact string without any hidden character like UTF-8 BOM or similar?

```
$string = chr(239).chr(187).chr(191).'{"cmp_class":"ProfileReferences","auto_id":"cmp14","forms":[],"parent":{"cmp_class":"PrivateMediaNetworkList","auto_id":"httpdoc"}}';
var_dump($string); // returns your string, although there are hidden chars

$nodeArray = json_decode($string,true);
var_dump($nodeArray); // returns NULL
```

Try comparing it with:

```
$string = '{"cmp_class":"ProfileReferences","auto_id":"cmp14","forms":[],"parent":{"cmp_class":"PrivateMediaNetworkList","auto_id":"httpdoc"}}';
var_dump($_REQUEST['COM_node'] == $string);
```

If the result is false, you'll need to find out, which characters to trim away.

EDIT:
You can modify you string to get only the part beginning with the first { and ending with the last }

```
preg_match("/{(.*)}/",$string,$matches);
$string = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Hmm. When I found strlen of $_REQUEST['COM_node'] and the string it self they are different

Answer (score 0):

Passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()` returns an array. You’ll have to use `print_r()` to view it; `echo()` won’t work.

```
php > $string = '{"cmp_class":"ProfileReferences","auto_id":"cmp14","forms":[],"parent":{"cmp_class":"PrivateMediaNetworkList","auto_id":"httpdoc"}}';
php > echo json_decode($string, true);
PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in php shell code on line 1

php > print_r($json_decode($string, true));
Array
(
    [cmp_class] => ProfileReferences
    [auto_id] => cmp14
    [forms] => Array
        (
        )

    [parent] => Array
        (
            [cmp_class] => PrivateMediaNetworkList
            [auto_id] => httpdoc
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first steep to debug problem is to get an error. You may use the function `json_last_error_msg()` or pass the flag `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` to the `json_decode()`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

The second steep would be to dump a hex representation of Your string. There are few invisible characters that may break JSON.

```
var_dump(bin2hex($string));
```